# QPrintDialog is shown twice in windows

Tags: c++, qt, qprinter

I've written this piece of code which takes the contents of a QPlainTextEditor and then sends that to a QPrint object it the the user accepts QPrintDialog

```
void MainWindow::on_actionPrint_triggered()
{
    printPage = new QPrinter(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    QPrintDialog *printDialog = new QPrintDialog(printPage,this);
    printDialog->show();
    if(printDialog->exec() == QPrintDialog::Accepted){
        QPainter *painterToPrnt = new QPainter;
        painterToPrnt->begin(printPage);
        painterToPrnt->drawText(printPage->pageRect(),ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText());
        painterToPrnt->end();
    }
}
```

it works OK under KDE (didn't try that under Gnome), but in Windows, whenever I accepts the printDialog, the dialog will be shown again and if I accept that again, it will send the text to the printer.

how can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's enough to call only `exec()`. You can remove the call of `show()`.

Comment: exec() calls show() internally and then blocks in an event loop.